# Webpack JS Template Strings to generate Inline CSS style for background image: url()

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, template-strings

I have the following template string in JS:

```
`<div class="card-img center-auto" alt="Image of ${data.title}" class="${data.imgClass}" style="background-image: url(images/${data.imageName}.JPG)"></div>`
```

The background image is an inline style which file path name gets loaded in with `data.imageName` on run.

Images load in DEV, and if I open PROD environment locally images are there but when I push it up to Github pages the images are error 404. I've waited while as I know it can sometimes take time to upload to GitHub pages but still nothing.

Images folder is called "Images" in same root as the index.html

How do I get Webpack to load these images? I've tried file-loader, url-loader and either I have configured wrong or should be using something else? Thanks

Webpack config DEV:

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  entry: {
    app: "./src/scripts/script.js"
  },
  devtool: "eval-source-map",
  devServer: {
    contentBase: "./dev"
  },
  output: {
    filename: "[name].bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dev")
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "url-loader",
            options: {
              limit: 8192
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)$/,
        use: [
          "file-loader",
          {
            loader: "image-webpack-loader",
            options: {
              mozjpeg: {
                progressive: true,
                quality: 65
              },
              // optipng.enabled: false will disable optipng
              optipng: {
                enabled: false
              },
              pngquant: {
                quality: "65-90",
                speed: 4
              },
              gifsicle: {
                interlaced: false
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Webpack Prod Config:

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const path = require("path");
const UglifyJSPlugin = require("uglifyjs-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require("optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  mode: "production",
  entry: {
    app: "./src/scripts/script.js"
  },
  devtool: "source-map",
  plugins: [
    new UglifyJSPlugin({
      cache: true,
      sourceMap: true
    }),
    new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({}),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "process.env.NODE_ENV": JSON.stringify("production")
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      // Options similar to the same options in webpackOptions.output
      // both options are optional
      filename: "[name].css",
      chunkFilename: "[id].css"
    })
  ],
  output: {
    filename: "[name].bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "docs")
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(html)$/,
        use: {
          loader: "html-loader",
          options: {
            attrs: [":data-src", "img:src"],
            minimize: true
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        loader: "svg-inline-loader"
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: Figure it out for some reason GitHub was remembering .jpg for images even tho I had changed it to .JPG and pushed up the changes, I re did the images in Prod re added and republished and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Figure it out for some reason GitHub was remembering .jpg for images even tho I had changed it to .JPG and pushed up the changes, I re did the images in Prod re added and republished and it worked.